# Instruction latencies in Instruments.app dissassembly gone with Xcode 4.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm

The Instruments.app that comes with Xcode 4.3.3 showed the latency and cycle count to the right of each instruction in the dissassembly view. It even told you where the pipeline would stall due to dependencies, and which registers are invovled.

All of that seems gone with Xcode 4.4 - the dissassembly now looks just like it does for x86 code (apart from the instructions being ARM, of course ;-)).

Does anyone know if that functionality can be re-gained? Or are there maybe third-party tool with the same capability?